# What is the correct way to ask someone to take a photograph of us?

Tags: phrase-request

What is the correct way to ask someone to take a photograph for us

> Excuse me, can you take a picture of us?

OR

> Excuse me, can you picture us?

Comment: Just smile and gesture with the camera.

Comment: Where? When? In what context? How many people is "us"? In an English-speaking country? At a theme park or tourist attraction or at a restaurant or just on the street somewhere? On the bus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the first one: "Excuse me, can you take a picture of us?". This asks somebody to take a photograph of you.

The second, "Excuse me, can you picture us?", is a valid sentence, but means something entirely different. It asks somebody if they can "picture" you in their mind, or "imagine" you. It's not a very common sentence, but it does make sense.

Comment: You may find they respond better if you say *please* at the end, or *Excuse me, please would you mind taking a picture of us?*

Answer (score -3):

I agree with Karnivaurus. "Excuse me, can you take a picture of us?" sounds more direct.

"Can you take us a picture?" is another alternative sentence.

To make it more polite as WS2 has pointed out, I usually use "would you please" at the beginning of the sentence. For example, "Would you please take us a picture?"

Comment: *Would you (please) **take us a picture**?* is not at all idiomatic English.

Comment: "Can you take us a picture?" is not an alternative at all it is completely wrong. the person would understand as you were waving a camera.